# Call Fragment B from Fragment A using ViewPager Tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have done many programs, where I have implemented multiple Fragments inside a Single Activity, but not when using Single Activity to host multiple Fragments as Tabs and then on Tap show another Fragments...

Using MaterialViewPager [library](https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager), in which I am calling different different Fragments to show views in their respective Tabs.

Like For the First Tab, I am using two Fragments, where

In First Fragment, I am using RecyclerView... to show list of Menus.

And in Second Fragment, I am using RecyclerView... to show list of Items under particular Menu.

So here my question is How to call Fragment from Fragment.

```
mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), mRecyclerView ,new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                Value value = valueList.get(position);
                List<Learning> learning = value.getLearning();

                // using when putting "item" data into same recyclerview
                // but on back press just exiting, not showing list of Menus again
                /**
                learningAdapter = new LearningAdapter(learning, R.layout.card_learning, getActivity());
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(learningAdapter);
                **/

                ItemFragment fragment = new ItemFragment();
                replaceFragment(fragment);

            }
```

Method replaceFragment

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment someFragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    // using Fragment not Activity, so where can I use frame_container in xml
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, someFragment); 
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: what's wrong here ??? why it has been downvoted ?

Comment: check my answer.no worries. your question is clear.

Answer (score 1):

you can have a callback interface that is implemented by the activity which hosts these two fragments. Fragment A will use the call back to notify the activity to replace A with fragment B. Depending on your need, you can pass parameters across through the callback method itself.

Your callback interface:

```
public interface YourCallback {
    public void methodWhichReplacesFragmentAwithB(params...);
}
```

Your Activity hosting fragments:

```
public class YourActivity extends ... implements YourCallback {
  ..
  ..
  @Override
  public void methodWhichReplacesFragmentAwithB(params...) {
    //insert replace fragment code here
  }
}
```

Your fragment will have a callback object, `YourCallback callbackObj;`. This callback object can be initialised using the activity *(pass as `this` from activity)* itself since the activity has the implementation of the interface. Now, you can use

`callbackObj.methodWhichReplacesFragmentAwithB(actual_params...);`

to replace the fragment. This callback interface can be exploited for other communications to parent Activity as well as other fragment hosted in that activity.

Comment: if you elaborate the answer it could be helpful to question owner.

Comment: I have done many programs, where I have implemented multiple Fragments inside a Single Activity, but not when using Single Activity to host multiple Fragments as Tabs and then on Tap show another Fragments...

Comment: @Sophie I have added an explanation. Let me know, if it doesn't fit your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

To replace fragment,

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, someFragment).addToBackStack("null").commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = ((AppCompatActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is One option which i have been using from long time before. I  will added the solution with clear example.

So you want to pass the value from `fragment A` to `fragment B`

So, here what you want to do is, you have pass the value through the activity.

1) you pass the value from `fragment A` to `activity`

2) then `activity` to `fragment B`

**Step 1:** first create an Interface Like below in `fragment A`

```
   public interface HomePage {
      void onHomeButtonsClicked(String clickedButton);
   }

   public void setOnHomeButtonClicked(HomePage homePage) {
     this.homePage = homePage;
   }
```

**Step 2:** then create the instance like below in Activity. where fragment created in PagerAdapter

```
 ((FragmentA) fragment).setOnHomeButtonClicked(new FragmentA.HomePage() {
                    @Override
                    public void onHomeButtonsClicked(String buttonClicked) {                         
                            pageSelected.onHomeButtonsClicked(selectedPage);                          
                        }
                    }
                });
```

**Step 3:** then create the interface in Activity like below.

```
public interface PageSelected {
    void onHomeButtonsClicked(String clickedButton);
}

public void setOnHomeButtonClicked(PageSelected pageSelected) {
    this.pageSelected = pageSelected;
}
```

**step 3:** then add the following method in `fragment B` in onCreateView or onResume()

```
  ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setOnHomeButtonClicked(new MainActivity.PageSelected() {
        @Override
        public void onHomeButtonsClicked(String clickedButton) {
            //fragment B received the value here 
        }
    });
```

**Step 5:** finally add the line in `fragment A` in button click or where you want to pass the value.

```
 homePage.onHomeButtonsClicked("Some String , by this code it is in String. you can change in your own data type");
```

You can rise your question if you face any difficulties.