# Sending data to the container activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have this issue of sending some data back and forth between a fragment and its container activity, I succeeded in doing it. What puzzles me is sending my data from the fragment to the activity, at first I implemented `OnResume()`, `OnStop()` and sent the data through an intent and that created an infinite loop so I removed them. Then I did `setRetainInstance(true)` and it worked and gave me the wanted behavior.

My Question is How my data are really being sent and where in the fragment lifecycle ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: i answered on this link. you can check on this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277624/call-fragment-b-from-fragment-a-using-viewpager-tabs/43278790#43278790

Comment: you can check this link also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android/38741476#38741476

Comment: I am not looking for the how to do it, I am not implementing any of the lifecycle methods nor intents, nothing I just specified the `setRetainState(true)`, Why the data is being sent and how I want to undrestand the logic behind it

Comment: to add some context in the container activity its `new Fragment()` each time I enter my fragment.

Answer (score 1):

The Right approach is to use Interfaces. Don't use onStop or setRetainInstance()

See this. It will solve you problem.
[Pass data from fragment to actvity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439941/passing-data-between-fragments-to-activity)

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this by using `Interface`,  using an `EventBus` like `LocalBroadcastManager`, or starting a new `Activity` with an `Intent` and some form of `flag` passed into its `extras` Bundle or something else.

**Here is an example about using Interface:**

**1.** Add function `sendDataToActivity()` into the interface (`EventListener`).

```
//EventListener.java

public interface EventListener {

    public void sendDataToActivity(String data);
}
```

**2.** Implement this functions in your `MainActivity`.

```
// MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements EventListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void sendDataToActivity(String data) {
        Log.i("MainActivity", "sendDataToActivity: " + data);
    }
}
```

**3.** Create the listener in `MyFragment` and `attach` it to the `Activity`.

**4.** Finally, call function using `listener.sendDataToActivity("Hello World!")`.

```
// MyFragment.java 

public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private EventListener listener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if(activity instanceof EventListener) {
            listener = (EventListener)activity;
        } else {
            // Throw an error!
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);

        // Send data
        listener.sendDataToActivity("Hello World!");

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();

        listener = null;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: +1 for the effort and explanation, am aware that I can do it using an interface, but my problem is to understand how I did it now ? does the `setRetainState(true)` is the one doing it for me althoug am making a new instance of myfragment each time or what ?